# "Non-naive" bayesian classification algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, classification, bayesian, naive-bayes

*Based on the problem description in this post:
[Relating parameters to a measured variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161770/relating-parameters-to-a-measured-variable)*

---

Based on a suggestion, I thought of studying the relationship between the parameters and a measured metric using Naive-Bayes classification. As, I was reading about it, I got to know that it assumes conditional independence i.e. P(x<sub>1</sub> | A,x<sub>2</sub>) = P(x<sub>1</sub> | A), where x<sub>1</sub>  and x<sub>2</sub> are parameters.

This may not be true in my case. **Are there similar classification algorithms that do not assume independence?** I understand that I may require higher number of samples but I can get them because this data is obtained from simulations.

*It would be nice if I do not have to code one for myself; so please let me know if R-packages may be available?*

Comment: In addition to Dougal's answer: for equal-variance multivariate-normally distributed data in each class, the Bayes classifier is linear discriminant analysis, and for unequal variance it is quadratic discriminant analysis. As a first step I'd recommend to try LDA.

Answer (score 2):

For a classification problem with data $X$ and labels $Y \in \mathcal{Y}$, if you know the exact distributions, the classifier least likely to make a mistake (the [Bayes classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_classifier)) is given by
\begin{align}
\hat{y}(x)
&= \arg\max_{y \in \mathcal{Y}} P(Y = y \mid X = x)
\\&= \arg\max_{y \in \mathcal{Y}} \frac{P(X = x \mid Y = y) P(Y = y)}{P(X = x)}
\\&= \arg\max_{y \in \mathcal{Y}} P(X = x \mid Y = y) P(Y = y)
.\end{align}
Since of course in practice we don't know those distributions, we can replace them by an estimate.

The Naive Bayes classifier follows from assuming the components of $X$ are independent, and using some density estimator or another on each dimension of $X$.

The $k$-nearest neighbor classifier is basically equivalent to using a $k$-NN density estimator for $P(X = x \mid Y = y)$ (the built-in [`knn`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/class/html/knn.html) function). Using kernel density estimation gives you a kernel-based classifier ([the `np` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/np/index.html) does this well, though I don't think it has a built-in classifier). These make no independence assumptions.

As @Jacques notes, you can do similar thing with so-called [Bayesian networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network), which assumes an independence structure according to a particular graph; you can attempt to learn that graph from the data.

Many other classifiers can also be cast in this framework.

Comment: How well does random forest fare against these methods? Someone told me that it performs better than naive-bayes, and so, I was reading about it.

Comment: Very dataset dependent, but if you just throw random forests at your raw data you're probably more likely to get a good result. They don't really fit into this model very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

The package [bnlearn](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/bnlearn/functions/bnlearn-package) have different forms of "learning the Bayesian network" from the data.